# I want Purchasedate in Date field in Edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The below fields 
1.Name
2.gender
3.price
4.email
5.payment

All are stored in database. But Purchase date is not stored in database. The all fields are showed in Edit user form, except purchase date is not showed.

**_form.html.erb**

```
      <%= form_for(@user, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="content">

    <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="well well-sm">

                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend class="text-center header">New user</legend>

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                              <%= f.label :name %>
                              <%= f.text_field :name %>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                              <%= f.label :email %>
                              <%= f.text_field :email %>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                               <div class="col-md-8">
                              <%= f.label :price %>
                              <%= f.text_field :price %>
                            </div>    
                        </div>   
                <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="col-md-8 gender">
                          Gender:<br> 
                           <%= f.radio_button(:gender, "Male")%>
                          <%= f.label(:gender_option1, "Male") %>
                            <%= f.radio_button(:gender, "Female")%>
                            <%= f.label(:gender_option2, "Female") %>
                        </div>
                </div>
              <div class="form-group">

                          <div class="col-md-8 gender">
                             Payment:<br> 
                            <%= f.check_box(:payment) %>
                            <%= f.label(:Debitcard )%>
                            <%= f.check_box(:payment)%>
                            <%= f.label(:Creditcard) %>
                            <%= f.check_box(:payment) %>
                            <%= f.label(:cashondelivery)%> 
                          </div>
              </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <%= f.label :image %><br />
                                 <%= f.file_field :image %>
                            </div>
                </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                  <div class="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.label :purchasedate %><br />
                        <%= f.text_field :purchasedate ,:value => @purchasedate %>
                  </div>
            </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                           <%= f.submit %>
                       </div>
               </div>
                  </fieldset>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**schema.rb**

```
    create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         :null => false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.string   "payment"
    t.date     "purchasedate"
   end
end
```

**Purchase date **

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <%= f.label :purchasedate %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :purchasedate ,:value => @purchasedate %>
![enter image description here][1] </div>
```

I want to store purchase date in database and it's value displayed in Edit user form. Please help me.

Comment: is purchasedate on the controller params?

Comment: not updated in controller params

Answer (score 0):

`<%= f.text_field :purchasedate ,:value => @purchasedate %>`

use `:value =>  @user.purchasedate` instead of `:value => @purchasedate`